# enumerate() method for generic async array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, dispatch

Hi I try to create `enumerate()` method for my custom async array, but stil have compilation error. My Custom class looks like that:

```
class AsyncArray<T> {

private var array = [T]()
private var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "async_queue", attributes: .concurrent)

    func enumerated() -> EnumeratedSequence<[T]> {
        var value = EnumeratedSequence<[T]>() // compilation error Cannot invoke initializer for type 'EnumeratedSequence<[T]>' with no arguments
        queue.sync {
            value = self.array.enumerated()
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

how can I implement `enumerated()` method to my custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning to `value` only to immediately overwrite it in the `sync` call. There's no need.

`DispatchQueue.sync` lets you directly return a result:

```
import Dispatch

class AsyncArray<T> {
    private var array = [T]()
    private var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "async_queue", attributes: .concurrent)

    func enumerated() -> EnumeratedSequence<[T]> {
        return queue.sync {
            return self.array.enumerated()
        }
    }
}
```

For reference: If you needed to assign to a captured variable, as you tried to do (which would be necessary an `async` call, for example), it would look something like this:

```
import Dispatch

class AsyncArray<T> {
    private var array = [T]()
    private var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "async_queue", attributes: .concurrent)

    func enumerated() -> EnumeratedSequence<[T]> {
        var result: EnumeratedSequence<[T]>?
        return someAsyncCall {
            result = self.array.enumerated()
        }
        waitForAsyncCallToFinish()
        return result!
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for it! could you please explain this second option with `someAsyncCall` or give some example? I have a problem to image how does it work

Comment: @PiterPan A lot of APIs these days are designed around using completion handlers as a means of modelling asynchronous work. That a problem, because a lot of times you want to block and wait for a result, so you have to use something like a `DispatchSemaphore` to undo the work they did in making a call async. In this sort of scenario, it's typical to "return" a value through capturing a local variable `result` and assigning to it

Comment: but in this case better solution in my opinion is using a `.barrier` flag as a wait for result than semaphore. What do you think?

Comment: Yep, but that's only possible if the asynchronous API uses dispatch queues, and exposes the ability to schedule it on your own queue.